# Get all the information of rows and their count in one single Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using inner Join to get the list of users with some condition . its working  fine but i also want to calculate  the total count in one single Mysql query.  Here is the query :

```
select  username, hostname, sessiontable.status 
from usertable JOIN sessiontable 
ON usertable.users_id = sessiontable.session_id  
WHERE sessiontable.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

I have also tried `COUNT(*)` as total with the above query but it gives only the count and the empty fields . How can I get the count of all users who are seen within last 10 minutes.

Thanks

Comment: I think the join condition is wrong usertable.users_id = sessiontable.session_id

Comment: well am not sure because i am new to mysql  . but its working fine  without using count(*).   it gives me information from the Sessiontable using UserID from Usertable . e.g i have 20 users  so it  gives me 20 rowsinfo from sessiontable

Comment: do you have column named users_id  in sessiontable?

Answer (score 0):

use group by clause and count for the id

```
select  username, hostname, sessiontable.status, count(usertable.users_id) as total 
from usertable JOIN sessiontable 
ON usertable.users_id = sessiontable.session_id  
WHERE sessiontable.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
group by usertable.users_id
```

Comment: thanks its working fine . But i need  the  total count of users which satisfies the 10 minute condition   .  e.g   10 users total are in 10 minute interval